# How to get class name from an annotation for static method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pickle
import hashlib

def read_file(path):
    # Implement your read_file logic here
    pass

def write_file(path, content):
    # Implement your write_file logic here
    pass

class CachedStaticMethod:
    path = "cache"
    
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self  # Return the decorator instance for staticmethod to use
        return self.func.__get__(instance, owner)  # For regular methods

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cache_path = self.__get_path(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            content = read_file(cache_path)
            result = pickle.loads(content)
        except Exception as e:
            result = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
            content = pickle.dumps(result)
            write_file(cache_path, content)
        return result    

    def __get_path(self, *args, **kwargs):
        class_name = self.func.__qualname__.split('.<locals>', 1)[0]
        function_name = self.func.__name__
        
        hash_input = f"{class_name}.{function_name}({args}, {kwargs})".encode("utf-8")
        hash_value = hashlib.md5(hash_input).hexdigest()
        filename = f"{hash_value}.cache"
        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

class MyClass:
    @CachedStaticMethod
    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method(param1: int, param2: str) -> float:
        """
        This is a cached static method of MyClass.
        """
        result = 3.14 * param1 + len(param2)
        return result

# Usage
result1 = MyClass.my_static_method(5, "hello")
result2 = MyClass.my_static_method(5, "hello")  # Should use cached result

print(result1)
print(result2)
```

This is the Error it's throwing:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 54
> 55 # Usage
> ---> 56 result1 = MyClass.my_static_method(5, "hello")
> 57 result2 = MyClass.my_static_method(5, "hello")  # Should use cached result
> 58
>
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 23
> 24     def **call**(self, *args, **kwargs):
> ---> 25         cache_path = self.__get_path(*args, **kwargs)
> 26
> 27         try:
>
> in __get_path(self, *args, **kwargs)
> 35
> 36     def __get_path(self, *args, **kwargs):
> ---> 37         class_name = self.func.**qualname**.split('.', 1)[0]
> 38         function_name = self.func.**name**
> 39
>
> AttributeError: 'staticmethod' object has no attribute '**qualname**'

Comment: Now you just need to [edit] your post to actually [have a question in it](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: They didn't start doing that until Python 3.10. OP might be on <= 3.9. You could use `func.__func__.__qualname__` in that case..

Comment: Relevant change: [bpo-43682: @staticmethod inherits attributes](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/25268)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python version issue. staticmethods don't have a `__qualname__` until Python 3.10.

You could access the underlying function with `__func__`, but you're already implementing the descriptor protocol yourself, so it'd be easier to just not use `staticmethod` at all. Handling `staticmethod`'s functionality is straightforward and makes using your decorator simpler:

```
class CachedStaticMethod:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.func
    ...

class MyClass:
    # No @staticmethod
    @CachedStaticMethod
    def my_static_method(...):
        ...
```

Also, the way you've designed your `__get__`, you're only caching calls like `MyClass.my_static_method(...)`. Calls on an instance, `MyClass().my_static_method(...)`, bypass the cache, even though they still don't receive `self`. You might want to just remove your `__get__` entirely, so all calls use the cache.

If you really want to keep `self.func` as a staticmethod, then you could do `self.func.__func__.__qualname__` to get the qualname.

Comment: In case I don't want to remove staticmethod annotation from my_static_method, how can I get `class` name in `CachedStaticMethod.__get__`?

Comment: @user1633272: Answer expanded, but I wouldn't recommend designing your code that way.

Comment: This idea doesn't work.

Comment: @wim: Really? It seems to work in my tests.

Comment: Yeah, anything that deserves to be called `@CachedStaticMethod` needs to cache on the type and the instance. Seems you've already discovered that limitation and mentioned it in the recent edit, but it may as well be a cached module level function if it will only work on the type directly. And there are a couple of other footguns lurking here.